How to create dockerfile for poetry+fastapi?
My dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11

# Устанавливаем рабочую директорию
WORKDIR /code

# Устанавливаем Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

# Устанавливаем Poetry в PATH
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"

# Копируем файлы конфигурации Poetry для установки зависимостей
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# Устанавливаем только runtime зависимости
RUN poetry install

# Копируем весь проект
COPY . .

CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app", "--workers", "4", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]


But when I try to run the image:
docker run -p 8000:8000 9018d1d9fb3bfa6779f8af4ba99079a870a065f68ad63e55f5c3c77e45e011f5
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "gunicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.


I've tried to create a "traditional" dockerfile with requirements.txt and it worked. Maybe it's normal to use poetry on locally and requirements.txt with pip in dockerfile? Or I need to use poetry in dockerfile too?

Error suggests that it couldn't find gunicorn in PATH.
Make sure that gunicorn is listed in pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
gunicorn = "^20.0.4"
uvicorn = "^0.13.4"

Also you can update your Dockerfile like this:
FROM python:3.11

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

# Add Poetry to PATH
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"

# Copy Poetry configuration files
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# Install dependencies (runtime only)
RUN poetry install --no-dev

# Copy the entire project
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application will run on
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run the application
CMD ["gunicorn", "main:app", "--workers", "4", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

Build and run docker image:
docker build -t your-image-name .
docker run -p 8000:8000 your-image-name


pyproject.toml is alright. Have tried your dockerfile and still have that gunicorn error.

Connect to container: docker run -it your-image-name /bin/bash and verify: gunicorn --version

This didn't work in my case. Just falled with poetry: command not found
